# creating a new column with lists in pandas df based another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe where some of the rows have multiple entries. I would like to match up a list I have to the third column. I have tried different things, but it isn't working for some reason.

**Current df**

```
username_list= ["charles23", "ems12", "", "sam34", "jon134", "", "jy19"]


ID1     ID2   passcode                    
01      01    Charlie233, Emily13         
01      02    
01      03    Sam310, John12               
01      04    
01      05    Jake42
```

**Desired df**

```
ID1     ID2   passcode                     username
01      01    Charlie233, Emily13          charles23, ems12
01      02                                
01      03    Sam310, John12               sam34, jon134
01      04                                
01      05    Jake42                       jy19
```

**What I tried**

```
df = df.assign(passcode = df["passcode"].str.split(",")).explode(column="passcode").assign(username=username_list).groupby(["ID1", "ID2"])["passcode", "username"].agg(list)

df.assign(
    passcode=df["passcode"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x) if x else ""),
    username=df["username"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
).reset_index()
```

ValueError: Length of values (1000) does not match length of index (1008)

I don't know why this error keeps happening given that I checked len(username_list) == len(df["passcode"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['pl'] = df['passcode'].str.split(',').str.len()
df['pi'] = df['pl'].cumsum() - df['pl']
df['username'] = df.apply(lambda x:username_list[x['pi']:x['pi'] + x['pl']], 
                      axis=1).str.join(',')
df.drop(['pi', 'pl'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

output (print(df)):

```
   ID1  ID2             passcode         username
0    1    1  Charlie233, Emily13  charles23,ems12
1    1    2                                      
2    1    3       Sam310, John12     sam34,jon134
3    1    4                                      
4    1    5               Jake42             jy19
```

---

**Explanation**:

Lets look at the `username_list` first, what we can see here is it is aligned with the values in `passcode` but we need to know where to start and where to stop for each list of words, for that the trick below works:

```
df['pl'] = df['passcode'].str.split(',').str.len()
df['pi'] = df['pl'].cumsum()-df['pl']
```

where `pl` is the passcode length and `pi` indicates where the next passcode starts at.

Then use these to go through your `username_list` to slice it and then join the list with ',' using pandas str.join method

```
df['username'] = df.apply(
        lambda x:username_list[x['pi']:x['pi'] + x['pl']], axis=1).str.join(',')
```

Then drop the columns `pi`, `pl`

```
df.drop(['pi', 'pl'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```